# SQLite - Entity Framework - Create Database from Model

Tags: sqlite, frameworks, entity

I'm trying to using SQLite provider with Entity Framework without luck.

I create a simple model edmx (Model first) and then I try to create a database form model, but I get an error message from Visual Studio IDE like foloowing image attached:
[image]
Any idea?

**@@EDIT**

After resinstalling SQLIte provider for VS 2013, now I get another error when I try to create database from model:
[image]